# Error Message occurs continuously in Form_Closing() event

Tags: vb.net-2010

I don't know what's wrong with this code . This message-box pops-up whenever I open any Form.

The code :

```
   Private Sub main_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, _
e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Dim dialog As DialogResult
        dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?", _
"LOGOUT?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If dialog = DialogResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            Application.ExitThread()
        End If      
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not remove the code if you don't need it?

Comment: i need this code... will you please help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need this code"? If the message box should not be opened anywhere, just remove the code. If you need anything else, please edit your question to contain all such information

Comment: Don't use phrases like 'Please help me', because we will, weather you said it or not.